# quickly try line of code and work with variables in visual studio code

Tags: python, variables, visual-studio-code, spyder

I am more used to Spyder and very new in vsc. In Spyder you have a python console where you can quickly try a codesnipped like:

```
print(len(a))
```

without having to run the entire code.
Is that also possible in vsc? I have not seen anything.

In addition, I can only see the variables in the debug mode. In Spyder I have all variables after one run at hand and can try and experiment on the fly with them. Is there another Variable-viewer plugin or how could that be enabled?

Comment: Sorry if you dislike this question, however, I could not really find any answer so I tried here. 
To give a hand, where should I have asked the question instead?

Comment: try the interactive python, see the docs

Comment: I did not thought of this. Actually quite simple. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/itemdetails?itemName=ms-python.python) of python. It has a Jupyter Notebook feature that comes with a variable explorer. It is recommended to also add the Jupyter extension as well (they work together just fine), you can find it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).

You can read [this documentary](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) about how to use Jupyter with visual studio code, you can see that it shows how to display the variables the way you wanted.

Comment: Geat, thanks a lot. I am looking forward using all the neet functionalities of vsc

Comment: I have to ask if that is only possible in jupyter? I worked a lot with jupyter, but for larger projects and due to other issues I often use Spyder (interchanging). 
Is there another way for the variable viewing/editing directly in vsc? Thanks

Comment: Using Jupyter is the only way I know of to work this way. Other than that, python is a scripting language so you can know each value and run effect of a single row when that row arrives. For larger projects you will have to write and debug your code traditionally.

Comment: Cheers. No wonder I did not find anything. Thanks a lot for helping me out. Stay save and have a nice day

Comment: No problem! Happy to help